# what SPQuery.RowLimit return

Tags: 2013, spquery, row-limit

In the below code what `query.RowLimit = 3` will return. i guess if i got 10 values in `query` variable, then `query.RowLimit = 3` will return first 3 values, Am i correct? or it will return somthing else?

```
SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
                        query.Query = @"<Where>
                                        <Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='field1'/><Value Type='Lookup'>" + value.ToString() + @"</Value></Eq>
                                        <Eq><FieldRef Name='field2' /><Value Type='Text'>" + "value2" + @"</Value></Eq></Or>
                                        </Where>";
                        query.RowLimit = 3; // what it will return
                        careerOpportunities = list.GetItems(query);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gets or sets a limit for the number of items returned in the query per page. So 3 Means, this will return the 3 rows.

The RowLimit property contains a value that corresponds to the value of the RowLimit element in Collaborative Application Markup Language.

The RowLimit property is used together with the ListItemCollectionPosition property to define paging in a query. Specifically, the SPListItemCollectionPosition object that is held in the ListItemCollectionPosition property is used to iterate through all the items in a collection n items at a time, where n is the value specified as a row limit.

[SPQuery.RowLimit Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.spquery.rowlimit(v=office.14).aspx)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb687949.aspx#UsingSPQueryObjs

Comment: first 3 values, right?